# Starcraft 2 site like wowhead for linking units/buildings/etc

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there any site like wowhead to paste a link in forums for units and buildings?

http://www.wowhead.com/tooltips

Examples:
http://static.wowhead.com/widgets/power/demo.html

Comment: Recommendation questions are not constructive and also specifically disallowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet for something like this is probably [Liquidpedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Main_Page).

For example, here's their entry on [Medivacs](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Medivac)

Comment: I mean on mouse hover, I want to see the medevac info on mouse hover like in wowhead and similar sites.